# File keeps reverting to previous version

Tags: texmaker, filesystem-access

To prevent all of my files from having a lot of `\usepackage{...}`'s and such in the top of the document, I've made my own .sty file.

I've placed the file in the `/Program Files (x86)/Texmaker/CustomPackages/tex/latex` folder. (I'm using Texmaker on Windows).

The problem is that I noticed that when I changed the .sty file and saved it, it would revert to its previous version, so I can't change it. I've even tried copying the file to my desktop, editing it, saving it and then placing it back. However, even that doesn't work. When I open the file when its on my Desktop, it is the edited version, but when I open the file once I've placed it back into the folder, it's the old version again.

I have no idea what's going on, since this hasn't always been a problem.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I suspect that this is a Windows file access permissions issue, completely unrelated to the TeX installation or to the TeXmaker program.  Putting personal files inside installation folders is usually not a good idea.  Additionally inside of Windows the Program Folders are somewhat restricted in access unless you are running as Admin (which is a very, very very bad idea).  So recommend you read http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/doc/2.9/miktex.pdf  pp22-30.  If you are running Tex-Live then refer to that appropriate manual.   I

Comment: Well, somehow, that did the trick. I changed the rights to the folder to read-only, then changed it back, and now it works like it should. I still have no idea what caused it to happen, but I'm glad I can at least modify my file.